# Boid Particles wont climb

Tags: particles, physics

I am trying to have a swarm of insects climb a wall.However the climb checkbox doesnt have an effect when it comes to climbing objects like walls that have a 90 degree angle.

[image]

Is there a way to have the particles change direction? Facing up and not only on the x or y axis.

However when the mesh has a diffrent angle,the particles climb,still a bit glitchy but they actually climb.

[image]

Comment: The way I THINK this works is that they look to take the shortest path to their target. I'd suggest making the wall much wider to make it so that going over is the shortest path. If you need your wall to not look any wider in the render then you'll need to use two objects - the particle collider being invisible in the render. Also worth checking that they actually can climb sheer vertical surfaces - the slightest incline might be necessary.

Comment: It looks like boid particles arent able to climb objects with a 90 degree angle,changing the wall angle slightly will solve the issue but the climbing effect is glitchy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antz -  (insects of the fast crawly kind)

This was placed as an answer to replace the upvoted comment above.  (the video link will be taken down in a month and the comment deleted)

First up -  in the 1st Blend file, the (antz) emitter cache has been ticked as 'External' .   Without that the saved file would have been some 15 MB. (as against less than 1 MB with it ticked)
Untick the box to make it work.

The alhpa layered video was rendered using OpenGL but Blender's internal render should also do it. (vers 2.77)

To play that after you've rendered yours, try ATL-A if the 2.77 UI was also imported.

.

Objective -

Insects (we'll call them 'Antz')  are to swarm along a path and climb a small vertical wall to get to a target. Once  there, they swarm around that location.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Antz, Boids and Particles aren't all that easy to control but there is a
workaround...

Two Blend files were used here -

- The 1st, to produce an alpha-layered video of the antz running along a straight unobstructed path and being inhibited from proceeding past the target.
- The 2nd file sets up a long stretched image plane (a path) and that's textured with the alpha-layered video from the 1st.

The "Generated" mapping mode for the texture was used. (not UV)

A curve modifier is used to shape the image-plane up & over the wall in  the 2nd file.

Several subdivisions in the curve at the wall's location will sharpen it up so it can wrap over the wall's vertical surfaces without shallow bends.

The plane (path) is also subdivided more heavily at the wall's proximity so it can be more neatly wrapped over the wall by the curve.

-===============-

The alpha layered Antz video from the 1st file -

The camera points down but perpendicular to the image plane which is sloped to use gravity rather than a Force-field to more gently influence the antz to proceed to the target, induce them also to mill around there.

The camera is best switched to orthographic mode in it's properties.
(use the 'Orthographic Scale' slider to zoom)

It's frame dimensions have to reflect those of the plane's, and in this case, that turned out to be 2503 x 384 pixels.  (400 .png files with an alpha layer)
(Dimension are in the Render 'Dimension' panel)

Set the file's output 'Shading' panel to 'Transparent' and the png output file to 'RGBA'

The Antz are herded along an invisible 'guide' that's a specially shaped corridor to ensure they don't go wandering off the path.

.

In the 2nd file -

Tick the 'Auto Refresh' box in the 'Texture --> Image-panel'  to play the video.

1st Blend file -
[image]

2nd -  [image]